# Unable to keep node.js server live with forever / pm2 / nohup

Tags: node.js, pm2, forever, nohup

I have a node.js application deployed and running on a virtual private server with a hosting provider.

I have installed the forever module. When I log in via ssh, traverse to the node application folder and run

```
forever start app.js
```

The application starts and prints

```
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
info:    Forever processing file: app.js
```

However as soon as I logout of ssh or close terminal and refresh my web application page it gives me 503 service unavailable error.

First I thought it might be because of the two warnings regarding minUptime and spinSleepTime that the server stops so I did

```
forever start --minUptime 1000 --spinSleepTime 1000 app.js
```

The server runs but then again when exited from ssh/terminal gives a 503 error.

I even tried running

```
nohup node app.js &
```

But again, server runs and upon exiting ssh gives 503.

I installed pm2 and ran

```
pm2 start app.js
```

But then exact same thing.

My package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "test-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My Application",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://username@bitbucket.org/reponame/mytest-app.git"
  },
  "author": "First Last",
  "license": "ISC",
  "homepage": "https://bitbucket.org/reponame/mytest-app#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^2.6.1",
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "connect-multiparty": "^2.1.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "express-handlebars": "^3.0.0",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "multer": "^1.3.0",
    "mysql": "^2.15.0",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "shortid": "^2.2.8",
    "uuid": "^3.2.1",
    "winston": "^2.4.2"
  }
}
```

Anyone has any idea what is going on? Why does the app stop when I exit the terminal? Do I need to add anything additional to my package.json like a start script?

Comment: Have you tried to log any errors from your script into a log file? I can see winston on your dependencies so I assume you are doing that. What do you see on your forever logs? `forever logs` will return a list of logs and then you can do something like `forever logs 0` to see that log. Have you tried opening a second session to the same server and monitor the log from there? Have you tried running the same script on a different VPS?

Comment: Be sure to install pm2 globally.

Comment: When I run forever logs or logs 0 it says Cannot find forever process: 0. Yes I have installed pm2 globally

Comment: did you able to fix it anyhow? i am having exact same issue

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is running on Linux - Create a shell script like below - this will restart the app if it is running.
You can update the script to only start the App. I use this script to restart my app after any changes are done. replace the port # on which your app is running.
Below script is for port 3005 and is starting the node app via app.js
Update a suitable location where you would want to see the error and output log.

You can also try to fork a process which would run the app instead of this script, so that when you logout the process continues to run - this will not require forever module.

```
#!/bin/bash
PID1=`netstat -antp 2>/dev/null|grep ':::3005'|awk '{print $7}'`
PID=`echo $PID1| cut -f1 -d "/"`
echo "$PID"
if [[ "$PID" ]];
  then
  echo "Stopping App running on process ID $PID"
  forever stop "$PID"
  echo "App stopped"
else
  echo "App not running"
fi
echo 'starting'
forever -m5 -o "../../output.log" -e 
"../../error.log" start app.js
echo 'started'
exit
```